# Suppose $H$ and $K$ are normal in $G$ and $H \bigcap K = \{e\}$. Show that $HK = G$

Tags: group-theory

Suppose $H$ and $K$ are normal in $G$ and $H \bigcap K = \{e\}$.   Show that $HK = G$

Since both $H$ and $K$ are normal, we have the property that for every $g \in G$, $g^{-1}Kg = K$ and $g^{-1}Hg = H$.  Further we have $H \bigcap K = \{e\}$.  So $H(H \bigcap K) = H\{e\}$ i.e. $H \bigcap HK = H$.  Similarly $K \bigcap HK = K$.  This means that $H \bigcup K \subseteq KH$.  Now for each $g \in G$ we have $g^{-1}(H \bigcup K)g = g^{-1}Hg \bigcup g^{-1}Kg \subseteq g^{-1}KHg$, so $HK$ is normal.

Now I know that if $HK$ is normal, it's order divided by the order of the intersection of $H$ and $K$ which is the trivial group of order 1 will equal the order of $G$.  Since the order of $HK$ = order of $G$, we have that $HK = G$.

Is this correct?  If not, please help me find the right steps.

Comment: Is $G$ is a finite group?

Comment: Yes, $G$ is finite.

Comment: What if $H=K=e$?

Comment: This is false without some further assumptions -- take $H = K = \{e\}$ subgroups of any nontrivial $G$.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  As it stands, the statement you seek to prove is false.  Are you implicitly making some assumptions regarding $G,H,K$ that you didn't mention?  Or does the counterexample end the question?

Comment: As $|HK| = |H||K|/|H \cap K| = |H||K|$, you won't have $G=HK$ unless $|G| = |H||K|$. For a nontrivial counterexample, take $G = \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$ and let $H$ and $K$ be any two distinct subgroups of order $2$.

Comment: I think $H$ and $K$ are meant to be nontrivial

Answer (score 1):

This is not true: let $G=S_3 \times S_3$, $H=A_3 \times \{1\}$ and $K=\{1\} \times A_3$. Then $|G:HK|=4$.

What you can conclude is that $H$ and $K$ commute.

Comment: Yes typo, thanks, edited.